# Why Running SQL script(.sql) from MySQL command line has no effects on database?

Tags: mysql, cmd, sql-scripts

I'm trying to run an `init.sql` script(including database creation, procedure creation, table creation, data insertion) file like this:

- `mysql.exe -u root -p <password> <my_db> < init.sql`.

But don't know why after invoking this line it will show output like below and nothing happens to the database?!

#### Configuration

- OS: `Windows 10(1809)`
- MySQL: `8.0.17`

#### Output:

> mysql  Ver 8.0.17 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
>   Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights
>   reserved.
>
> Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
>   affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.
>
> Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]   -?, --help          Display this
>   help and exit.   -I, --help          Synonym for -?   --auto-rehash
>   Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to use
>                         'rehash' to get table and field completion, but startup
>                         and reconnecting may take a longer time. Disable with
>                         --disable-auto-rehash.
>                         (Defaults to on; use --skip-auto-rehash to disable.)   -A, --no-auto-rehash
>                         No automatic rehashing. One has to use 'rehash' to get
>                         table and field completion. This gives a quicker start of
>                         mysql and disables rehashing on reconnect.   --auto-vertical-output
>                         Automatically switch to vertical output mode if the
>                         result is wider than the terminal width.   -B, --batch         Don't use history file. Disable interactive behavior.
>                         (Enables --silent.)   --bind-address=name IP address to bind to.   --binary-as-hex     Print binary data as hex
>   --character-sets-dir=name
>                         Directory for character set files.   --column-type-info  Display column type information.   -c, --comments      Preserve comments. Send comments to the server. The
>                         default is --skip-comments (discard comments), enable
>                         with --comments.   -C, --compress      Use compression in server/client protocol.   -#, --debug[=#]     This is a
>   non-debug version. Catch this and exit.   --debug-check       This is
>   a non-debug version. Catch this and exit.   -T, --debug-info    This
>   is a non-debug version. Catch this and exit.   -D, --database=name
>   Database to use.   --default-character-set=name
>                         Set the default character set.   --delimiter=name    Delimiter to be used.   --enable-cleartext-plugin
>                         Enable/disable the clear text authentication plugin.   -e, --execute=name  Execute command and quit. (Disables
>   --force and history
>                         file.)   -E, --vertical      Print the output of a query (rows) vertically.   -f, --force         Continue even if we
>   get an SQL error.   --histignore=name   A colon-separated list of
>   patterns to keep statements
>                         from getting logged into syslog and mysql history.   -G, --named-commands
>                         Enable named commands. Named commands mean this program's
>                         internal commands; see mysql> help . When enabled, the
>                         named commands can be used from any line of the query,
>                         otherwise only from the first line, before an enter.
>                         Disable with --disable-named-commands. This option is
>                         disabled by default.   -i, --ignore-spaces Ignore space after function names.   --init-command=name SQL Command
>   to execute when connecting to MySQL server.
>                         Will automatically be re-executed when reconnecting.   --local-infile      Enable/disable LOAD DATA LOCAL
>   INFILE.   -b, --no-beep       Turn off beep on error.   -h,
>   --host=name     Connect to host.   -H, --html          Produce HTML output.   -X, --xml           Produce XML output.   --line-numbers
>   Write line numbers for errors.
>                         (Defaults to on; use --skip-line-numbers to disable.)   -L, --skip-line-numbers
>                         Don't write line number for errors.   -n, --unbuffered    Flush buffer after each query.   --column-names      Write column names in results.
>                         (Defaults to on; use --skip-column-names to disable.)   -N, --skip-column-names
>                         Don't write column names in results.   --sigint-ignore     Ignore SIGINT (CTRL-C).   -o, --one-database  Ignore statements except those that occur while the
>                         default database is the one named at the command line.   -p, --password[=name]
>                         Password to use when connecting to server. If password is
>                         not given it's asked from the tty.   -W, --pipe          Use named pipes to connect to server.   -P, --port=#        Port
>   number to use for connection or 0 for default to, in
>                         order of preference, my.cnf, $MYSQL_TCP_PORT,
>                         /etc/services, built-in default (3306).   --prompt=name       Set the mysql prompt to this value.   --protocol=name     The protocol to use for connection (tcp, socket, pipe,
>                         memory).   -q, --quick         Don't cache result, print it row by row. This may slow
>                         down the server if the output is suspended. Doesn't use
>                         history file.   -r, --raw           Write fields without conversion. Used with --batch.   --reconnect         Reconnect
>   if the connection is lost. Disable with
>                         --disable-reconnect. This option is enabled by default.
>                         (Defaults to on; use --skip-reconnect to disable.)   -s, --silent        Be more silent. Print results with a
>   tab as separator,
>                         each row on new line.   --shared-memory-base-name=name
>                         Base name of shared memory.   -S, --socket=name   The socket file to use for connection.   --server-public-key-path=name
>                         File path to the server public RSA key in PEM format.   --get-server-public-key
>                         Get server public key   --ssl-mode=name     SSL connection mode.   --ssl-ca=name       CA file in PEM format.
>   --ssl-capath=name   CA directory.   --ssl-cert=name     X509 cert in PEM format.   --ssl-cipher=name   SSL cipher to use.   --ssl-key=name 
>   X509 key in PEM format.   --ssl-crl=name      Certificate revocation
>   list.   --ssl-crlpath=name  Certificate revocation list path.
>   --tls-version=name  TLS version to use, permitted values are: TLSv1, TLSv1.1,
>                         TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3   --ssl-fips-mode=name
>                         SSL FIPS mode (applies only for OpenSSL); permitted
>                         values are: OFF, ON, STRICT   --tls-ciphersuites=name
>                         TLS v1.3 cipher to use.   -t, --table         Output in table format.   --tee=name          Append everything into
>   outfile. See interactive help (\h)
>                         also. Does not work in batch mode. Disable with
>                         --disable-tee. This option is disabled by default.   -u, --user=name     User for login if not current user.
>   -U, --safe-updates  Only allow UPDATE and DELETE that uses keys.   -U, --i-am-a-dummy  Synonym for option --safe-updates, -U.   -v, --verbose       Write more. (-v -v -v gives the table output format).   -V, --version 
>   Output version information and exit.   -w, --wait          Wait and
>   retry if connection is down.   --connect-timeout=# Number of seconds
>   before connection timeout.   --max-allowed-packet=#
>                         The maximum packet length to send to or receive from
>                         server.   --net-buffer-length=#
>                         The buffer size for TCP/IP and socket communication.   --select-limit=#    Automatic limit for SELECT when
>   using --safe-updates.   --max-join-size=#   Automatic limit for rows
>   in a join when using
>                         --safe-updates.   --show-warnings     Show warnings after every statement.   -j, --syslog        Log filtered
>   interactive commands to syslog. Filtering of
>                         commands depends on the patterns supplied via histignore
>                         option besides the default patterns.   --plugin-dir=name   Directory for client-side plugins.   --default-auth=name Default authentication client-side plugin to use.   --binary-mode       By default, ASCII '\0' is disallowed and '\r\n' is
>                         translated to '\n'. This switch turns off both features,
>                         and also turns off parsing of all clientcommands except
>                         \C and DELIMITER, in non-interactive mode (for input
>                         piped to mysql or loaded using the 'source' command).
>                         This is necessary when processing output from mysqlbinlog
>                         that may contain blobs.   --connect-expired-password
>                         Notify the server that this client is prepared to handle
>                         expired password sandbox mode.
>
> Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
>   C:\WINDOWS\my.ini C:\WINDOWS\my.cnf C:\my.ini C:\my.cnf C:\Program
>   Files\MySQL\my.ini C:\Program Files\MySQL\my.cnf The following groups
>   are read: mysql client The following options may be given as the first
>   argument:
>   --print-defaults        Print the program argument list and exit.
>   --no-defaults           Don't read default options from any option file,
>                           except for login file.
>   --defaults-file=#       Only read default options from the given file #.
>   --defaults-extra-file=# Read this file after the global files are read.
>   --defaults-group-suffix=#
>                           Also read groups with concat(group, suffix)
>   --login-path=#          Read this path from the login file.
>
> Variables (--variable-name=value) and boolean options {FALSE|TRUE} 
>   Value (after reading options)
>   --------------------------------- ---------------------------------------- auto-rehash                       TRUE auto-vertical-output              FALSE bind-address
>   (No default value) binary-as-hex                     FALSE
>   character-sets-dir                (No default value) column-type-info 
>   FALSE comments                          FALSE compress
>   FALSE database                          (No default value)
>   default-character-set             auto delimiter
>   ; enable-cleartext-plugin           FALSE vertical
>   FALSE force                             FALSE histignore
>   (No default value) named-commands                    FALSE
>   ignore-spaces                     FALSE init-command
>   (No default value) local-infile                      FALSE no-beep
>   FALSE host                              (No default value) html
>   FALSE xml                               FALSE line-numbers
>   TRUE unbuffered                        FALSE column-names
>   TRUE sigint-ignore                     FALSE port
>   0 prompt                            mysql> quick
>   FALSE raw                               FALSE reconnect
>   FALSE shared-memory-base-name           (No default value) socket
>   (No default value) server-public-key-path            (No default
>   value) get-server-public-key             FALSE ssl-ca
>   (No default value) ssl-capath                        (No default
>   value) ssl-cert                          (No default value) ssl-cipher
>   (No default value) ssl-key                           (No default
>   value) ssl-crl                           (No default value)
>   ssl-crlpath                       (No default value) tls-version
>   (No default value) tls-ciphersuites                  (No default
>   value) table                             FALSE user
>   root safe-updates                      FALSE i-am-a-dummy
>   FALSE connect-timeout                   0 max-allowed-packet
>   16777216 net-buffer-length                 16384 select-limit
>   1000 max-join-size                     1000000 show-warnings
>   FALSE plugin-dir                        (No default value)
>   default-auth                      (No default value) binary-mode
>   FALSE connect-expired-password          FALSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you showed is the help output of the mysql client. It didn't run your init.sql script at all. It didn't get that far, because it didn't understand your command to invoke the client.

I don't use Windows, but I understand that the `<` input redirection doesn't work in Powershell. You can run an SQL script in a different way, without using input redirection:

```
mysql ...options... -e "source init.sql"
```

Also you should understand that the `-p` option for the mysql client doesn't work if you have a space between the `-p` and the password.

Use either:

```
mysql -p<password> ...
```

Or:

```
mysql --password=<password> ...
```

But my preference is to avoid putting username & password on the command line at all. Put them in an options file, described here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but we expect `mysql` some warning if it didn't understand the command or the wrong options

Comment: It's pretty standard for a command to output the help when it doesn't understand your command. That's what it did in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest following the [MySQL8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html) documentation as described. Try to fully qualify **--user** and **--password** as follows:

```
shell> mysql --user=user_name --password=pass db_name
```

[List of options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html)